# VirtualBox and its own physical ethernet card?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox, ethernet

we use an IBM x3500 M3 with two physical ethernet cards. one is actually for the ubuntu which virtualize a mac os x by using virtual box. so there's one unused ethernet card. therefore, i want to use this card for the virtual box mac os x only, so it gets its own ip and is accessible from the ubuntu machine and the other clients in the network. how can i do that? which settings do i have to use and which network mode? nat? bridge? any suggestions?

thanks in advance.

so long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your physical hardware always has to go through VirtualBox. That's the entire idea of having virtual machines, to make them completely independent of the underlying hardware. If you look closely, your virtual machine does not see the actual hardware, it sees the emulated hardware provided by VirtualBox. In fact, within VirtualBox you can select which type of ethernet card it should emulate and that is what the guest OS will see (and use drivers for).

In other words, set up a bridge, just like you did for the first card, and away you are.